# Binary expansion and correspondence of finite strings

Tags: logic, computability

How can we show that there is a one-to one correspondence between finite strings of the symbols 1 and 0 and the naturals $\mathbb{N}$. I was thinking along the lines of maybe using a 2-tuple, but couldnt get far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Represent each finite string as an ordered pair in the following way: the first element of the pair is the interpretation of the string as a natural number, and the second is the number of leading zeroes. Now use any bijection between $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Can you also be more explicit on the bijection between N x N and N?

Comment: @BuddyHolly: The [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) is one very nice bijection between $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N$. Your description of $f$ in the first comment bears no resemblance to what I suggested, which would, for example, take the string $0000101$ to the pair $\langle 5,4\rangle$: $0000101$ as a binary number represents the number $5$, and it has $4$ leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

A poem for you, dear OP:

> Order the strings by length ascendingly,
>
> and among strings of the same length lexicographically.
>
> "$n$-th in this order" matches strings to natural numbers bijectively.
>
> Prove it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $n \in \mathbb{N}$. There will be $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $2^k \le n < 2^{k + 1}$. Now consider $n - 2^k$, rinse and repeat.